# Does binance use SEPA while withdrawing euro when we use sepa?

Tags: money-transfer

My bank deducted a portion of money that I withdrew from binance to my eur account?
I asked santander bank in poland they answered:

- 0 PLN for transfer in EUR, from the EEA (European Economic Area) country other than Poland,
- 5 PLN for SEPA transfers, 
  I tried it and they deducted around 1.1 Eur.
  On the other hand, pko bank answered :
  PLN 0 - SEPA transfer order -
  PLN 11.00 - Transfer order from foreign banks (other than SEPA transfer order)
  I did not try this but I want to know what does this mean? Binance sent from UK and when they say sepa it is not correct actually! UK is not sepa and the bank deducted my money. I asked again from pko again they said:
  The United Kingdom is no longer a member of the European Union, therefore we may charge a fee of PLN 11.00 (or currency equivalent) for receiving a transfer.

Anybody any idea?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Euro_Payments_Area), UK is a SEPA member even after leaving EU.

Comment: wiki is not correct. since the bank deducted the money

Comment: So from this fact you deduct that the Wiki is wrong? You completely exclude the possibility that e. g. there may be fees under certain circumstances although both countries are SEPA member? The rule that EUR payments don't have to cost more than a domestic payment is a EU directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-EU countries can be part of SEPA, but transfers from/to there are not "protected" by EU directives.